How do I log out of the Shopify API at the same time as my Astro app?
I am trying to implement user auth using the Shopify Headless customer account API in an Astro app with auth-astro. I have set up my Shopify store with the Headless app properly, I can log in, maintain a session and it all works nicely. What I can't work out how to do is log out properly. Even if I use the built-in Log out method of AuthJS, the Shopify account remains logged in.
The correct method to log out of Shopify is a GET request to their endpoint with the ID token as a URL parameter as documented here: https://shopify.dev/docs/api/customer#step-logging-out
The AuthJS docs don't have much on how to edit the logout functions. It simply clears your local session data and redirects you to a local URL. https://authjs.dev/getting-started/session-management/login
My auth.config.mjs file looks like the following and this is where I guess I need to make the change.
import { defineConfig } from 'auth-astro';
const CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT = `#graphql
query {
    customer {
        id
        emailAddress { 
            emailAddress 
        }
        firstName
        lastName
    }
}`;

export default defineConfig({
    providers: [
        {
            id: 'shopify',
            name: 'Shopify',
            type: 'oauth',
            clientId: import.meta.env.PUBLIC_SHOPIFY_CUSTOMER_ACCESS_TOKEN,
            clientSecret: import.meta.env.PRIVATE_SHOPIFY_CUSTOMER_ACCESS_TOKEN,
            issuer: `https://shopify.com/authentication/${import.meta.env.PUBLIC_SHOPIFY_STORE_ID}`,
            authorization: {
                url: `https://shopify.com/${import.meta.env.PUBLIC_SHOPIFY_STORE_ID}/auth/oauth/authorize`,
                params: {
                    scope: 'openid email https://api.customers.com/auth/customer.graphql',
                    client_id: import.meta.env.PUBLIC_SHOPIFY_CUSTOMER_ACCESS_TOKEN,
                    response_type: 'code',
                    redirect_uri: `${import.meta.env.SITE_URL}/api/auth/callback/shopify`,
                },
            },
            token: {
                url: `https://shopify.com/authentication/${import.meta.env.PUBLIC_SHOPIFY_STORE_ID}/oauth/token`,
                params: {
                    client_id: import.meta.env.PUBLIC_SHOPIFY_CUSTOMER_ACCESS_TOKEN,
                    client_secret: import.meta.env.PRIVATE_SHOPIFY_CUSTOMER_ACCESS_TOKEN,
                    grant_type: 'authorization_code',
                    redirect_uri: `${import.meta.env.SITE_URL}/api/auth/callback/shopify`,
                },
            },
            userinfo: {
                url: `https://shopify.com/${import.meta.env.PUBLIC_SHOPIFY_STORE_ID}/account/customer/api/${import.meta.env.SHOPIFY_APP_VERSION}/graphql`,
                async request(context) {
                    const response = await fetch(this.url, {
                        method: 'POST',
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                            Authorization: `${context.tokens.access_token}`,
                        },
                        body: JSON.stringify({
                            operationName: 'GetCustomer',
                            query: CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT,
                            variables: {},
                        }),
                    });
                    const { data } = await response.json();
                    const { customer } = data;
                    customer.id_token = context.tokens.id_token;
                    return customer;
                }
            },
            profile(data) {
                return {
                    id: data.id,
                    firstName: data.firstName,
                    lastName: data.lastName,
                    email: data.emailAddress.emailAddress,
                    id_token: data.id_token,
                };
            }
        },
    ],
    callbacks: {
        async session({ session, token }) {
            if (token) {
                session.user = token.user;
            }
            return session;
        },
        async jwt({ token, user, profile }) {
            if (user) {
                token.user = user;
            }
            if (profile && profile.id) {
                token.graphId = profile.id;
            }
            return token;
        },
    },
});

I considered using events, but they're asynchronous and therefore a get request to the Shopify logout URL wouldn't be appropriate as the users browser has to navigate to the URL.
I tried redirecting back from Shopify to the logout route of AuthJS but because it's a GET and not a POST request it renders a logout confirmation page.
My best guess is to use the redirect callback in AuthJS somehow https://authjs.dev/reference/core/types#redirect perhaps by inspecting the local URL and redirecting to Shopify as the users session ends. I am not sure how I could retrieve the users id_token from the session in that instance.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I solved this in a fairly roundabout kind of way with redirects. It has the desired effect but it doesn't feel right.
On logout click the user goes to a local app route which builds the Shopify logout URL with the ID token as a parameter and redirects there. The Shopify page has a logout redirect back to a new URL on the app. That URL has a script tag that executes the logout POST request and then finally redirects the user to the home URL.
Tested and it does work as expected but if Shopify ever release an endpoint to log out via a POST request I'll be switching to that.
